# nfs, execution denied

Tags: fstab, nfs

I have server (debian 6) machine (say, ip = 10.13.13.100) with nfs exports

**/etc/exports**

```
 /path/to/my/shared/folder 10.13.13.0/24(rw,async,no_sub_tree_check,no_root_squash)
```

There are two users on this machine `admin` (uid = 1000) and `user` (uid = 1001)

on client machines (also debian 6) (say, ip = 10.13.13.111) i have
**/etc/fstab**

```
 10.13.13.100:/path/to/my/shared/folder /my/mount/point nfs rw,exec,user,owner 0 0
```

There is only one `user` (uid = 1000)

after `reboot` or `mount -a`, the shared folder is mounted successfully, but i can not execute any file on it (even if files have exec permissions). However, read and write for files on this file system works fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

May be the noexec flag is set.

Comment: I have the `noexec` flag for my shared folder entry in /etc/mtab.. even if I remove the entry from mtab and than unmount and mount the shared folder, the `noexec` appears again.. Why? And how can i fix this???

Comment: It is the default for nfs. You may add the exec option to change it.

Comment: Should I add it to client:/etc/mtab? or server:/etc/exports? or client:/etc/fstab?

Comment: /etc/fstab, i think, but not really sure, sorry. :-)

Comment: its already in fstab, and still does not work=( thanks anyway

Answer (score 17):

The culprit is the `user` option you have used in `/etc/fstab`, and specifically that you have placed the `exec` option *before* the `user` option.

From `man mount`:

> **user**: Allow an ordinary user to mount the filesystem. ... This option implies the options  **noexec**,  **nosuid**,
>   and **nodev** (unless overridden by *subsequent* options, as in the option line **user,exec,dev,suid**).

I suppose this behaviour is for security reasons. Anyhow, whenever you use `user`, you should specifically add an `exec` option if that is what you want *and it should be **after** the `user` option* to override the `noexec` implied by `user`.

Comment: `168.192.74.30:/volume1/nfs /mnt/nfs nfs defaults,user,exec,dev,suid 0 0` in my fstab and I can run .sh scripts from my nfs share again

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed the issue by changing the client:/etc/fstab contents to the following:

```
10.13.13.100:/path/to/my/shared/folder /my/mount/point nfs rw,exec 0 0
```

Comment: This won't allow sudo-less mount though.